# Mostrar elementos de um array em ordem aleatória

Tags: javascript

Tenho um código que pede para usuário informar o número de pessoas, depois peço para ele informar o nome das pessoas, só que quando mostra na tela, ele deveria trazer para mim assim, segue abaixo:

```
numeroPessoa = 4
nome = raphael
nome = gabi
nome = jorge
nome = alex
```

Ao apresentar o nome na tela no final do código deveria ser apresentado da seguinte maneira abaixo:

```
nome = gabi
nome = alex
nome = raphael
nome = jorge
```

Dessa forma aleatória, e não na ordem que foi armazenado no meu vetor. Segue código abaixo:

```html
<script>

    

function gerar(fim){
          
          return Math.floor(Math.random()* fim )+ 1;

        }
         
          numeroPessoas = window.prompt("Digite um numero de pessoas");
          fim = numeroPessoas;
           vetor = new Array ();
           for (i = 1 ; i <= numeroPessoas; i++){
            
                var nome = window.prompt("Digite o nome");
                vetor.push([i] +"º" + " -" + " " +  nome + " ");
                

           }
            
             for (j = 0; j < numeroPessoas; j++){
                   
                  k = gerar(numeroPessoas.length);

              
                    document.write(vetor[K] + "<br>" + "<hr>");
               
          

             }
        
          
    

 </script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Olha, encontrei os seguintes problemas:

- K maiúsculo no índice do array
- Somar + 1 no random, isso pode acessar uma posição inexistente do array
- numeroPessoas.length, já é um número, portanto não dá pra acessar a propriedade lenght
- fim = numeroPessoas; você declara a variável, porém a função recebe como parâmetro

Corrigindo esses pontos, o código funcionou, mas existe a possibilidade de repetir as pessoas nesse random criado:

```html
<script>

  function gerar(fim){
    //Remoção do + 1 para evitar acessar um índice inexistente do array
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * fim );
  }

  let numeroPessoas = window.prompt("Digite um numero de pessoas");
  let vetor = new Array();

  for (i = 1 ; i <= numeroPessoas; i++){  
    let nome = window.prompt("Digite o nome");
    vetor.push([i] +"º" + " -" + " " +  nome + " ");
  }

  for (j = 0; j < numeroPessoas; j++){
    k = gerar(numeroPessoas); // Ou usar o vetor.lenght
    document.write(vetor[k] + "<br>" + "<hr>");
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Para evitar sortear o mesmo, poderia fazer um `array.slice()` retornando o nome da pessoa

Answer (score 2):

## Análise

Seu código apresenta muitos erros e não condiz com o que é proposto na pergunta, o que pode ser definido em passos:

**1. Coletar os dados**

**2. Embaralhar os dados**

**3. Exibir os dados**

O primeiro passo seu código conseguiu concluir com êxito, mas os dois últimos não. A função `gerar(fim)` não possui utilidade. Houve desatenção entre o declarar e o utilizar da variável `k`.

## Solução

Ao meu ver a solução é aproveitar o que você fez no primeiro passo, coletar os dados e implementar os outros dois passos: embaralhar os dados e exibir os dados.

**Embaralhar os dados**

Para embaralhar um array deve-se utilizar o [algoritmo de embaralhamento de Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). 
Esse algorítimo foi descrito em 1938 por Ronald Fisher e Frank Yates em seu trabalho *Statistical tables for biological, agricultural and medical research*(Tabelas estatísticas para pesquisa biológica, agrícola e médica).

O embaralhamento de Fisher-Yates é um algoritmo que gera uma permutação aleatória de uma seqüência finita - em termos simples, o algoritmo embaralha a sequência. O algoritmo funciona como se colocasse todos os elementos em um chapéu, ele determina continuamente o próximo elemento tirando aleatoriamente um elemento do chapéu até que nenhum elemento permaneça.

O algoritmo produz uma permutação imparcial: toda permutação é igualmente provável. A versão moderna do algoritmo é eficiente: leva tempo proporcional ao número de itens embaralhados e embaralha-os no lugar.

O algoritmo é bem simples:

```
- Para embaralhar uma matriz a[] de n elementos (índices 0..n-1):
    faça :i de n − 1 decrescer para 1 
      atribua :j ← inteiro aleatório tal que 0 ≤ j ≤ i
      trocar a[j] com a[i]
    fim faça
```

**Exibir os dados**

Para exibir os dados vou usar o método [`Console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/console/log) que exibe uma mensagem no console do navegador aliado ao método [`Array.Join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) que junta todos os elementos de uma array em uma string.

## Resposta

```js
//Coleta de dados aproveitada e simplificada a partir do seu código
numeroPessoas = window.prompt("Digite um numero de pessoas");
var vetor = new Array();
for (i = 0 ; i < numeroPessoas; i++){            
      vetor.push(window.prompt("Digite o nome"));
}

//Exibição dos dados
console.log('Número de pressoas:' + vetor.length + "\n");
console.log('Entrada:' + vetor.join("-") + "\n");
console.log('Embaralhado:' + embaralhar(vetor).join("-") + "\n");

   
// Algoritmo de embaralhamento de Fisher–Yates
function embaralhar(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
  return array;
}
```