# Embaralhar array digitada pelo usuário em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Quero que o usuário digite números na array e,ao clique do botão,o parágrafo exiba a array que ele digitou,mas embaralhada.O código abaixo não funciona,só se for uma array fixa,tipo : minhaArray = ['banana','maça','mamão'];

```js
valores = [];
function adicionaInput() {
  var quantidade = document.getElementById('ordenando');
  valores.push(quantidade.value);
  //quantidade.valores = "";  
}

function embaralhaArray() {
  //valores.sort((elem1,elem2)=>Math.random() - Math.random());
  document.getElementById("valores").innerHTML = valores.sort((elem1,elem2)=>Math.random() - Math.random());
}
```

```html
        <input type="text" id="ordenando">
        <button type="button" id="add" onclick="adicionaInput();">Add </button>
        <button type="button" id="display" onclick="embaralhaArray();">Mostrar</button>

        <div id='valores'></div>
```

Comment: Veja se essa resposta o ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/406059/137387

Comment: *"mas embaralhada"* vc quer dizer os mesmos valores, mas em uma ordem diferente?

Answer (score 0):

Estou a usar o algoritmo de Fisher–Yates para valores aleatorios, se ajudei otimo

```js
valores = [];
function adicionaInput() {
  var quantidade = document.getElementById('ordenando');
  valores.push(quantidade.value);
  //quantidade.valores = "";  
}

function embaralhaArray() {
  var atual = valores.length, tmpVal, iAlea;

  
  while (0 !== atual) {


   iAlea= Math.floor(Math.random() * atual);
   atual -= 1;

   tmpVal= valores[atual];
   valores[atual] = valores[iAlea];
   valores[iAlea] = tmpVal;
  }

  document.getElementById("valores").innerHTML = valores;
}
```

```html
        <input type="text" id="ordenando">
        <button type="button" id="add" onclick="adicionaInput();">Add </button>
        <button type="button" id="display" onclick="embaralhaArray();">Mostrar</button>

        <div id='valores'></div>
```